# Iterate through list of document uids and create listeners in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

In my Vuex store, I have an action that takes a list of uids of followed users from the current user's Firestore UserDataCollection document, iterates through them, and produces the data for each document to be shown on the UI. It works fine using .get(), but I'm trying to convert it to .onSnapshot() so that I can get real-time updates.

I have been totally unsuccessful trying to use .onSnapshot(), as I can't find any references online or in the Firebase docs on how to implement this after mapping through the array of uids.

I tried removing the promises, since onSnapshot doesn't seem to work with promises, and replaced the .get() with .onSnapshot(), but that didn't work.

Does anyone know the correct way to implement the Firestore .onSnapshot() listener given the code below?

```
getCircle({state, commit}) {
      const circle = state.userProfile.circle
      let promises = circle.map(u => userDataCollection.doc(u).get())
      
        return Promise.all(promises)

        .then(querySnapShot => {
          let circleData = []
          if (querySnapShot.empty) {
            console.log("empty")
          } else {
            querySnapShot.forEach(doc => {
              let item = doc.data()
              circleData.push(item)
             }
            )
          }
          commit('setUserCircle', circleData)
        })
   },
```

**Edit based on response**

I added .onSnapshot within the forEach as shown in the code below. In vue devtools it's showing the correct number of data entries in my Vuex store, however they are all undefined.

```
getCircle({state, commit}) {
  const circle = state.userProfile.circle
  let promises = circle.map(u => userDataCollection.doc(u).get())
  
    return Promise.all(promises)

    .then(querySnapShot => {
      let circleData = []
      if (querySnapShot.empty) {
        console.log("empty")
      } else {
        querySnapShot.forEach(x => {
          let itemId = x.data().uid
          userDataCollection.doc(itemId)
            .onSnapshot((doc) => {
              let item = doc.data()
              console.log(doc.data())
              circleData.push(item)
          })   
          }
        )
      }
      commit('setUserCircle', circleData)
    })
```

},

Comment: If you want to listen to changes in X individual documents, you'll have to establish X listeners, one for each document.  There's no easy way around this.  You can share the callback between them, though.  It's not clear from your question where you got stuck with this.

Comment: So you're saying that within the forEach, I need to implement the .onSnapshot()?

Comment: That sounds like a good place to start.

Comment: Updated question based on your response. It seems that the data is somewhat being processed, but comes back as undefined. However, at least the number of entries of undefined match the number of records that should be returned.

Comment: If you're having problems with your implementation, the question should indicate what specifically doesn't work the way you expect, and how you're observing that.  "comes back as undefined" isn't very specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the help. The solution that worked was to remove the .map and Promise and used an 'in' query. Code shown below:

```
 getCircle({state, commit}) {
   const circle = state.userProfile.circle

   userDataCollection.where('__name__', 'in', circle).onSnapshot(querySnapShot => {
    var circleData = []
    querySnapShot.forEach(doc => {
      let item = doc.data()
      circleData.push(item)
      commit('setUserCircle', circleData)
    })
  })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In presented code `commit` is run only once before `onSnapshot` callback. I tried to create example showing the mechanism (I am assuming that `circle` array is assigned properly and I have 3 items hardcode'ed in mine):

```
let promises = circle.map(u => userDataCollection.doc(u).get())

Promise.all(promises)
.then( querySnapShot =>  {
    var circleData = []
     querySnapShot.forEach( x  => {
        let itemId = x.data().uid
        userDataCollection.doc(itemId).onSnapshot(doc => {
            let item = doc.data()
            circleData.push(item)
            console.log("inside snapshot: ",circleData.length)
        })
    })
    console.log("outside foreach: ",circleData.length)
})
```

If you run this code you should see in console something like this (I have run this in node):

```
outside foreach:  0
inside snapshot:  1
inside snapshot:  2
inside snapshot:  3
```

And if you do any change in Firestore you will get another console log `inside snapshot:  4`.

I do not have full understanding of your application logic, however I think that `commit` statement should be inside `onSnapshot` listener. But of course, with information I have, this is only guess.

Comment: Thanks, I added the commit to be inside the listener. However, the data comes back as "undefined is not an object" when I try to reference the data in my UI.